# Using the same google fusion table, one query selection works and the other doesn't

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, google-visualization

Full code for this question is at [Test Application](http://www.wgianalytics.net/IMAP1/)

I am attempting to use a google fusion table with queries to display subsets of a database.  The code for the Project type (handlePrjTypeKey) produces the expected results; however, the code to select for City does not (no project shows).  I have spent a fair bit of time trying to figure out why and am at a loss.  I have confirmed that I can manually query the table in Google Fusion Tables with the same query string used in the following functions and get the expected results, but the program version isn't working.

Any assistance or suggestions would be most appreciated!

```
    function handlePrjTypeKey(queryString)
    {
    // Google Fusion PointFeat table
    var pntLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
        select: 'ProjectType',
        from: pntCityTableId,
            where: queryString
      },
          map: GlobalMap
        });

    // Google Fusion LineFeat table
    var linLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
        select: 'ProjectType',
        from: linCityTableId,
        where: queryString
        },
        styles: [{
            polylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeWeight: "2"
            }
        }],
          map: GlobalMap
        });

    // Google Fusion AreaFeat table
    var areaLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'ProjectType',
        from: areCityTableId,
            where: queryString
          },
          map: GlobalMap
        });
 }

function handleCityKey(queryString)
{
    // Google Fusion PointFeat table
    var pntLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
        select: 'CityName',
        from: pntCityTableId,
            where: queryString
      },
          map: GlobalMap
        });

    // Google Fusion LineFeat table
    var linLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
        select: 'CityName',
        from: linCityTableId,
        where: queryString
        },
        styles: [{
            polylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeWeight: "2"
            }
        }],
          map: GlobalMap
        });

    // Google Fusion AreaFeat table
    var areaLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'CityName',
        from: areCityTableId,
            where: queryString
          },
          map: GlobalMap
        });
}
```

The Table ID's are defined in the right.html file as shown

```
  // To simplify my life I decided to just use a couple of global variables instead of passing parameters!
  // These three tables have the project geometry merged with the project data
  var pntTableId = '16uiLeoNQIIonp6JxsOpKDxzT1S391pP9BZ-RnVQ'; // The fusiontables table id, encrypted form, needed to access the project data
  var linTableId = '1EHx68dEBTB4-uCoW1KdjhV6n_40QYMNq3VcwGjI';
  var areTableId = '1mP2PIX-C3s9y3kqzicl0xrCzZyDNAs78tH04aYc';
  // These three tables have the project geometry merged with the project data and the cities impacted
  var pntCityTableId = '1LV4c5hf4TGei9O90jge3guhZJ5YDVVMjiOgqI0w'; // The fusiontables table id, encrypted form, needed to access the project data
  var linCityTableId = '1zq9xgR8mnebZGbpjWYU16PpdxzohKpxjLi9JtDk';
  var areCityTableId = '1xyOrrqbvVjQ30jEut0Fc68T4rv5prZ9cFXU4fQk';
  var datalink = null;
  var GlobalMap = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is invalid.  It is returning an error:
"Could not parse query", the table with encrypted id 1mP2PIX-C3s9y3kqzicl0xrCzZyDNAs78tH04aYC doesn't seem to exist.

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1mP2PIX-C3s9y3kqzicl0xrCzZyDNAs78tH04aYc

All the queries in QueryFusionTables are returning errors because the "datalink" variable is null (at least on the municipality/city page).

If you don't need that functionality, perhaps it should be removed.  You should at least add error handling to it.

The reason no data is showing on the fusion table layer is the queryStiring "CityName = 'COCONUT+CREEK'" doesn't match any rows, the data in the CityName column is "COCONUT CREEK".  You need to translate the "+" to a " " (space) (or change the space in the column to a "+").

The "select" should be the geometry column, from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesQuery)

> select | string | A column, containing geographic features to be displayed on the map. See Fusion Tables Setup in the Maps API documentation for information about valid columns.

Change:

```
var pntLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
    select: 'CityName',
    from: pntCityTableId,
        where: queryString
  },
      map: GlobalMap
    });
```

To:

```
var pntLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: pntCityTableId,
        where: queryString
  },
      map: GlobalMap
    });
```

Comment: That table id ends with a lower case 'c' not an uppercase 'C'.   When I use that change it works,  when I look at the code where the table id's are defined 'right.html' it appears correct.  Where did you find the mistaken id?

Comment: Also, that id is associated with a table that is not being used by either of the above functions.  The type function is working, while the City function is not.

Comment: My typo (copy paste error in the ID).  That table is being queried in the QueryFusionTables function (and returning that error).

Comment: Thanks!  I've commented out the QueryFusionTables function--it is from a previous implementation and not updated for this yet.  I am still having the issue that the Type query is working while the City query is not.  I am at a loss as to why...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you update (forgot to refresh).  I have been testing with one word cities (DAVIE, MARGATE, ...) just in case the space was the problem.  They aren't working either, even though they do exist; queryString: "CityName = 'DAVIE'"

Comment: I have updated the script to change the + to a space and to select from the geometry column.  The behavior is still the same, the Type query works and the city query does not.

Comment: Your live version is working for me.  Did you do a refresh after fixing the scripts?

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I had, but it still didn't work until I exited and restarted the browser!  Much appreciated!